# Compare list of strings with object properties in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings that contain course codes, and a list of objects who have `courseCode` as a property.

I'm trying to find a linq expression to compare the two, and let me know if there are any matches, at all, between the items in the list of strings and the courseCode properties in the list of objects.

I had a working expression moments ago and, long story short, I do not anymore and it's a miracle my laptop and monitors aren't in a million pieces :)

Below is my current best guess at the comparison. `results` is the list of objects while `coursesThatWork` is the list of strings. The expression below gives the error message

> Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to return type 'bool'

```
results.Where(x => coursesThatWork.Where(y => y.Equals(x.CourseCode))).Count() == 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error because [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) expects a boolean predicate but you are again passing `Where` which return `IEnumarable<T>` and thus the error. You need [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) here which will return a boolean for matching condition:-

```
results.Where(x => coursesThatWork.Any(y => y.Equals(x.CourseCode))).Count() == 0
```

Comment: And maybe be consistent with the Any : `!results.Any(x => coursesThatWork.Any(y => y.Equals(x.CourseCode)))`